# Why isn't jQuery append method working when passing parent class to add a child input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I want to append a duplicate of an input box in a parent box. Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="reading-group input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reading link" id="link">         
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-reading-btn add-resource">+ Add another link</a>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
function addPlaceholder(parentClass){
  var placeHolder = $(parentClass).children().eq(0);
  $(parentClass).append(placeHolder);
  console.log(placeHolder);
}

$('.add-reading-btn').click(function(){
  addPlaceholder('.reading-group');
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekraj007/kexe6gxn/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are just appending same element, meaning you just move it to same place. You need to use a cloned element instead, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/kexe6gxn/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff you are right.

Comment: Abhishek .. check my answer you need to use `.clone()` to create a clone of the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is taking the existing `<input>` element and moving it from the `<div>` and back into the `<div>`, so it looks like nothing is happening.  If you `.clone()` the element and then `.append()` it, a new element will be added.

Here is a working example:

```js
function addPlaceholder(parentClass) {
  var placeHolder = $(parentClass).children().eq(0).clone();
  $(parentClass).append(placeHolder);
  console.log(placeHolder);
}

$('.add-reading-btn').click(function() {
  addPlaceholder('.reading-group');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reading-group input-group">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reading link" id="link">
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-reading-btn add-resource">+ Add another link</a>
```

If you want to add focus to your `<input>` element on load, you can do so by adding this line to the bottom of your code:

```
$('#link').focus();
```

If you want to add focus to the new element on creation, as well as give it an empty value rather than copying the prior element's value, add this line to the end of your `addPlaceholder()` function:

```
$(placeHolder).val("").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the `.clone()` method of jquery to create a clone of the textbox like below . You were only referring to the same element not the cloned html before.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function addPlaceholder(parentClass){
    var placeHolder = $(parentClass).children().eq(0).clone();
    $(parentClass).append(placeHolder);
    //console.log(placeHolder);
  }
  
  $('.add-reading-btn').click(function(){
    addPlaceholder('.reading-group');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reading-group input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reading link" id="link">         
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-reading-btn add-resource">+ Add another link</a>
```

Here is a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kexe6gxn/2/